# How do I implement a custom @JsonDeserialize method on an endpoint class?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jquery, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a class where I have a custom deserializer annotation:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ConvertToNullDeserializer.class)
public void setObject(Integer pObj) {
    this.pObj = pObj;
}
```

When this object is sent via ajax to the cloud endpoint I would like the custom deserailizer to fire, but instead I just get:

```
{
  "error" : {
"message" : "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Integer from String value 'null': not a valid Integer value\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: 
"code" : 400,
"errors" : [ {
  "domain" : "global",
  "reason" : "badRequest",
  "message" : "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Integer from String value 'null': not a valid Integer value\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: 
   } ]
 }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem completely, cloud-endpoints generally takes care of the serialization and deserialization for you. Perhaps a @JsonDeserialize annotation is not the path you want to take, because with endpoints your delegating away the json related stuff to the system.  What does your deserializer do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JsonDeserialize` isn't supported within Endpoints, but you can use an [`@ApiTransformer`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apitransformer) instead.

Marking a class for transformation:

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiTransformer;

@ApiTransformer(BarTransformer.class)
public class Bar {
  private final int x;
  private final int y;

  public Bar(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }
}
```

Example transformer:

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Transformer;

public class BarTransformer implements Transformer<Bar, String> {
  public String transformTo(Bar in) {
    return in.getX() + "," + in.getY();
  }

  public Bar transformFrom(String in) {
    String[] xy = in.split(",");
    return new Bar(Integer.parseInt(xy[0]), Integer.parseInt(xy[1]));
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for most cases, but fails when you have a dynamic json request that breaks the model (i.e. a field that can be a string or an object)